# What is the c# equivalent of Powershell [WMI] ResumeState method?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, wmi

In Powershell we have `[WMI] accelerator type` which has `ResumeState` method. Whats is the equivalent in .NET?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. `[WMI]` is a shortcut to typing `[Management.ManagementObject]`. That class doesn't have a `ResumeState` method. What WMI class are you asking about?

Comment: Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc146163.aspx

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I'm asking about class `MIIS_ManagementAgent`, I'm running following query: `gwmi -class MIIS_ManagementAgent -namespace "root/MicrosoftIdentityIntegrationServer"` and I'm running `ResumeState` on the output. How can I achieve the same thing in `c#`?